# Choppy Firefox Video Playback on OpenBSD

Tags: firefox, video, openbsd

I am having a problem playing audio/video through Firefox, using OpenBSD (tested using YouTube). The playback is choppy, as if the connection was not good enough.

On a media player the audio is fine, and video as well. When using any other operating system, I never had this issue.

What might be causing this issue to happen specifically on OpenBSD?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Windows 7 / Firefox 45 ESR and it only started recently. Firefox 38 ESR seems to work fine though. They probably screwed something up at YouTube.

Comment: @John the problem is related to OpenBSD. This is not a Firefox fault, in fact the OP probably can reproduce it also with Chrome.

Comment: @RufoElMagufo Are you sure about that? Perhaps the OP can try that and report back to us

Comment: @SimonSheehan yes, 100% sure. That's a known problem on OpenBSD. http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/firefox-vs-rthreads

Answer (score 1):

OpenBSD has some performance problems playing videos in Firefox. This is due to the excessive use in Firefox of some slow syscalls (which are fast in Linux). Firefox developers didn't test the code on OpenBSD, so they didn't detect the problem.

Use OpenBSD 5.9 or -current. Both include a temporary workaround for this problem.